# The img tag does not respect the parent's right margin

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image inside a div. When I resize the window I want the image to keep the same distance to the right as the div does. If I set the image as a background on another div it works fine, but couldn't figure out how to get it to work as an img tag as well:

Here's what it looks like

[image]

```css
.mainDiv {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.tempImage {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1200x183);
  height: 183px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <h2>This one works</h2>
  <div class="tempImage"></div>

  <h2>This one doesn't</h2>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x183" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the `max-width` property on the image, or overflow property on the container div, depending on whether you want the image to scale or be cutoff:

**max-width:**

```css
.mainDiv {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.tempImage {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1200x183);
  height: 183px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <h2>This one works</h2>
  <div class="tempImage"></div>

  <h2>So does this one</h2>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x183" alt="">
</div>
```

**overflow:**

```css
.mainDiv {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tempImage {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1200x183);
  height: 183px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <h2>This one works</h2>
  <div class="tempImage"></div>

  <h2>So does this one</h2>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x183" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.mainDiv {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.tempImage {
  background: url('https://dummyimage.com/1200x400/000/fff');
  height: 183px;
}

.img-class {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <h2>This one works</h2>
  <div class="tempImage"></div>

  <h2>This one does now?</h2>
  <img class="img-class" src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x400/000/fff" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried setting the width, but this will result in the image being resized as well.

Comment: Ah I see, now what you needed, didn't understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Try max-width property of the img tag.